Understand Doubly Robust Estimator with Right Censoring by Tsiatis (2006)
In Tsiatis 2006 chapter 10.4 page 254, a doubly robust estimating function for right censored data is defined. It also called augmented IPCW (AIPCW) estimating function.
The book is about developing efficient estimator when have coarsened data in general, but I pay particular attention in the case of right censored data, which is a type of monotone coarsening.
Let $m\left(Z_i, \beta\right)$ be the full data estimating function. Here is the corresponding AIPCW estimating equation:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\left[\frac{\Delta_i}{K_{U_i}\left\{\bar{X}_i\left(U_i\right)\right\}} m\left(Z_i, \beta\right)+\int_0^{\infty} \frac{d M_{\tilde{C}_i}\left\{r, \bar{X}_i(r)\right\}}{K_r\left\{\bar{X}_i(r)\right\}} E\{m(Z, \beta) \mid T \geq r, \bar{X}(r)\}
\right]=0
$$
My question is about the term $E\{m(Z, \beta) \mid T \geq r, \bar{X}(r)\}$. For simplicity, let $m(Z, \beta) = Z-\beta$ and assume only baseline covariates $X$ are measured. Furthermore, since $\beta$ is deterministic, my question is really about the following quantity $$E\{T\mid T \geq r, X\}.$$
One way (and honestly the only way I'm familiar with) to estimate this quantity is - first rewrite $$E\{T\mid T \geq r, X\}  = \frac{\int_r^\infty tdF(t\mid X)}{1-F(r|X)},$$ and then note that $1- F(\cdot \mid X) = S(\cdot \mid X),$ which is the conditional survival function.
Furthermore, $$S(r\mid X) = \exp\left\{ - \int_0^r \lambda(m)\,dm \right\},$$
where $$ \lambda(t) = \lim_{0\to 0^+} h^{-1} P(t\le T\le t+h\mid T\ge t, X)$$ is the hazard function of $T$ given $X$.
Certainly this is not estimable, but with censoring at random (CAR) assumption holds, we will have (and for now one can treat this as the definition of CAR)
$$ \lambda(t) = \lim_{0\to 0^+} h^{-1} P(t\le T\le t+h\mid T\ge t, X) =  \lim_{0\to 0^+} h^{-1} P(t\le T\le t+h\mid T\ge t,C\ge t, X),$$ which depends on observable data and thus estimable.
Note that so far, I can "flexibly switch" between conditioning only on $T\ge t$ to conditioning on $T\ge t, C\ge t$ because of the CAR assumption.
My Question: sometimes I hear and see people write $E\{T \mid T \geq r, X\}$ as $E\{T \mid T \geq r, C\ge r, X\}$ in the AIPCW estimating equation. But this way of writing brings confusion to me.
Seems to me that the writing of $E\{T \mid T \geq r, C\ge r, X\}$ suggests this quantity can be computed directly from the version of hazard $\lim_{0\to 0^+} h^{-1} P(t\le T\le t+h\mid T\ge t,C\ge t, X)$, without the use of CAR assumption to "flexibly switch". However I don't see it is true.
In more detail, suppose now we don't have CAR assumption, and we are able to estimate the version of hazard $\lambda(t)=\lim_{0\to 0^+} h^{-1} P(t\le T\le t+h\mid T\ge t,C\ge t, X)$. I understand that the quantity $$\exp\left\{ - \int_0^r \lambda(m)\,dm \right\}$$ no longer has the meaning of $S(r\mid X)$, but it will be a function of $T,C,X$, denote it as g(r, T, C,X).
Does $$E\{T\mid T \geq r, C\ge r, X\} \stackrel{?}{ =} \frac{\int_r^\infty t d\{1-g(t,T, C,X)\}}{g(r, T, C,X)}.$$
